# Different results from different Uber APIs

Tags: uber-api

I'm seeing different results from 2 different Uber APIs (both in uber.com/api).

First API is `www.uber.com/api/fare-estimate`, where's I'm seeing a `perMinute` price of $0.13.

Second API is `api.uber.com/v1.2/products/{product_id}`, where I'm seeing a `cost_per_distance` of $0.16.

Where is this difference coming from?  Which API should I be using?  When I use the UI to get a price estimate (www.uber.com/fare-estimate), I see the $0.13 price, not the $0.16, but I think the old API (www.uber.com/api/fare-estimate) is deprecated, isn't it?

Reference:
First API example: `curl https://www.uber.com/api/fare-estimate?pickupLat=39.739233&pickupLng=-104.990252&destinationLat=39.736160&destinationLng=-104.998695`

Second API example: `curl -H 'Authorization: Token {developer_token}' -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products/f464d065-be99-40bd-95b5-ac0c784930e8"`

Thanks, M.

Answer (score 0):

For the most accurate estimates you should use the price estimates endpoint (if not authed with a user) or the request estimates endpoint (if auth with user token). The price breakdown is deprecated as we move towards having an upfront fare. I would not rely on the price breakdown and use the price estimates endpoint for providing price estimates.